# Javascript performance when reassigning a value to a variable

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a boolean which is originally false. But in some future, if its value change (can change multiple times, but only to the same) will be true.

For example, with the given *pseudocode*

```
const hasChanged = false; // stateful

// This function can be called multipe times
const handleSubmit = () => {
   // ...
   hasChanged = true;
   // ...
}
```

I am always reassigning the value 'true' to my boolean... and I think that, maybe, it can be optimized by firstly checking if it is false, like this:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
   // ...
   !hasChanged && hasChanged = true;
   // ...
}
```

But this will only be true if the conditional check (read + check) is faster than the write operation in JS, something that I don't know.

Any ideas?

Comment: This feels like generally not something you should worry about at all, and as long as its not a getter/setter method you are not adding any additional overhead. The check, however, does add more overhead, definitely since JS is compiled JIT which means it needs to - technically - compile more code. Just assign the variable, as getting and checking from memory is probably the longer op. By a _teeeny meeny mini_ margin. So much that compromising the readability of your code is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assigning the value unconditionally, without testing it first, will probably be a smidgen faster:

> As a general rule of thumb, branches are slower than straight-line code (on all CPUs, and with all programming languages). -[jmrk, V8 developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166875/why-are-two-calls-to-string-charcodeat-faster-than-having-one-with-another-one/54186960#54186960)

This is the same line of reasoning behind the famous question: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)

That said, this is *extremely unlikely* to be a performance bottleneck. It's not worth worrying about.

The following micro-benchmark seems to bear this out, though micro-benchmarks are not all that reliable:

```js
const len = 1e8;
const arr = Array.from({ length: len }, () => Math.random() < 0.5);
setTimeout(() => {
  // Wait for window to load completely and be free of CPU load
  const t0 = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (!arr[i]) arr[i] = true;
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - t0);
}, 2000);
console.log('timeout set');
```

```js
const len = 1e8;
const arr = Array.from({ length: len }, () => Math.random() < 0.5);
setTimeout(() => {
  // Wait for window to load completely and be free of CPU load
  const t0 = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = true;
  }
  console.log(performance.now() - t0);
}, 2000);
console.log('timeout set');
```

On my machine, the conditional assignment takes 500ms or so on average, whereas the unconditional assignment takes 80ms or so on average.

Comment: I like that quote. And I fully agree, probably not a bottleneck _at all_.